# solving cubic diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Can someone show me how to find all solutions in positive integers to the diophantine equation: $$x^3 + y^3 = 35$$ I know how to do it algebraically, but I want to know how you solve it in number theory.

My Algebraic Approach:
$x^3 + y^3 = (x + y)\cdot (x^2 - xy + y^2) = 35$.

The only integer factors of $35$ are $(1, 35)$ or $(5, 7)$. There are no integers $x$ and $y$ that add to $1$, so $x + y = 5$ or $7$.

Using $x + y = 5$ we get that $y = 5 - x$, so $y^3 = 125 - 75x + 15x^2 - x^3$ so
$x^3 + y^3 = 15x^2 - 75x + 125 = 35$
or
$$15x^2 - 75x + 90 = 0$$
$$x^2 - 5x + 6 = 0$$
$$(x - 3)(x - 2) = 0$$
So $x = 2$ or $x = 3$
Thus $y = 3$ or $y = 2$ respectively.

Using $x + y = 7$ we get that $y = 7 - x$, so $y^3 = 343 - 147x + 21x^2 - x^3$ so
$$x^3 + y^3 = 21x^2 - 147x + 343 = 35$$
$$21x^2 - 147x + 308 = 0$$
$$3x^2 - 21x + 44 = 0$$
or
$$x = \frac{21 \pm \sqrt{-87}}{6}$$
Since x is complex, this can't be a solution.

So $(x, y) = (2, 3)$ or $(x, y) = (3, 2)$

Comment: what is your algebraic way? Please share so that help can be provided accordingly.

Comment: $4^3=64$, so $x$ and $y$ are both between $1$ and $3$, inclusive. Thus, an exhaustive search is far quicker than trying to be smart and slick.

Comment: It's $x^2\color{red}-xy+y^2$.

Comment: @Lucian Yeah I see. But, I don't want to do it this way. I want to learn the number theory approach.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Can you please help here?

Comment: @rachel: Your argument was number-theoretic, since you used the factorization of $35$. It was well done, but for a specific small number like $35$, it is an unnecessarily complicated approach.

Comment: @AndréNicolas But I am really curious to see it. Can you show it if you can

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "see it." As pointed out in comments and in the answer, we have $1\le x,y\le 3$, so the number of candidates is tiny. Your more number-theoretic approach is well-argued, and might be useful for a number much larger than $35$.

Comment: Now find all solutions in positive integers to $x^3+y^3=1729$, and then tell G H Hardy about it.

Comment: You dropped a minus sign in the line My Algebraic Approach, but it doesn't matter to the rest. Your approach is fine and finds the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You know that $x$ and $y$ cannot both be greater than or equal to $3$, because this would give you too large of a sum. And $x$ and $y$ must both be less than $4$ by similar reasoning. So in this case, that's probably the best way to approach the problem: Just try $1,2,3$ for $x$ and $y$, where they are not both $3$. And note you can assume $x \leq y$ by symmetry, and modify your answer after the fact based on symmetry and the solutions you get.

Answer (score 1):

To bound all solutions
in integers
(not just to positive integers)
to
$x^3+y^3 = n$:

First,
using the factorization
$x^3+y^3
=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)
$,
we get
possible values
for $x+y$
since $(x+y) | n$.
Then,
since
$x^2-xy+y^2
=(x+y)^2-3xy
$,
we get possible values
for $xy$
($xy
=\dfrac{(x+y)^2-n/(x+y)}{3}
$)
and
this gives $x$ and $y$.

Note (added after a comment):
If $a=x+y$ and $b=xy$ are known,
then,
since
$(r-x)(r-y)
=r^2-r(x+y)+xy
=r^2-ar+b
$,
$x$ and $y$
are the roots of
$r^2-ar+b$.
So use the quadratic formula:
$r
=\dfrac{a\pm \sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}
$.

(Additional stuff to make the solution explicit)

We have
$a = x+y$
 (the divisor of $n$), 
$b = xy = ((x+y)^2−n/(x+y))/3=(a^2−n/a)/3$. 
Then the discriminant
$d
=a^2-4b
=a^2-4(a^2−n/a)/3
=(4n/a-a^2)/3
=(4n-a^3)/(3a)
$
and the roots are
$\dfrac{a\pm \sqrt{(4n-a^3)/(3a)}}{2}$.
If we adopt the convention
that $x < y$,
then
$x = \dfrac{a- \sqrt{(4n-a^3)/(3a)}}{2}$
and
$y = \dfrac{a + \sqrt{(4n-a^3)/(3a)}}{2}$
.
For this to work,
$(4n-a^3)/(3a)$
must be a perfect square.

Some elementary bounds on $x$ and $y$:

If
$0 < x \le y$,
$\sqrt[3]{n/2} < y \lt \sqrt[3]{n}
$.

If $x < 0 < y$,
since
$x^2-xy+y^2
=x^2-xy+(y/2)^2+3y^2/4
=(x-y/2)^2+3y^2/4
> 3y^2/4
$,
$x+y > 0$
or
$y > -x$.

This can be improved to
$x^2-xy+y^2
=x(x-y)+y^2
=(-x)(y-x)+y^2
> y^2
$
and
$x^2-xy+y^2
<3y^2
$.

For every divisor $d$ of $n$,
$d y^2 < n < 3dy^2$,
so
$\sqrt{n/(3d)} < y < \sqrt{n/d}$.

Comment: And then how do I find x and y exactly?

Comment: I added an explanation. Essentially, use the quadratic formula.

Comment: In this case what is a and b

Comment: I don't understand what I plug into the quadratic formula for a and b.

Comment: a = x+y (the divisor of n), b = xy = $((x+y)^2-n/(x+y))/3 = (a^2-n/a)/2$.

Comment: I got to that point but i dont know how to go on

Comment: Added some more.

Comment: Among the infinity of rational solutions there is just a solution with both $x,y$ rational integers, the positive one $(3,2)$ (and the trivially "other" $(2,3)$)

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.-You have solved easily the problem algebraically and you want to know how solve it in number theory. Well your curve is an elliptic curve of rank $1$ whose generator is the point $(3,2)$ which is the only point of integer coordinates and it is determined using your algebraic way. For the rest it has an infinity of rational points whose set is dense in the curve and that can be calculated by the method of chords and tangents. That is what number theory in connection with elliptic curves  tells us about this problem (algebraic number theory deals with the other non-rational  algebraic points, i.e. non trascendental, of the curve).