# solve the following equation for x and y

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve the following equation for x and y:
$$xy=\frac{(x+y)^2-\frac{35}{x+y}}{3}$$
I tried using the quadratic formula, but can't figure out completely.

This is what I had though I could do:
If $a=x+y$ and $b=xy$ are known,
then,
since
$(r-x)(r-y)
=r^2-r(x+y)+xy
=r^2-ar+b
$,
$x$ and $y$
are the roots of
$r^2-ar+b$.
So we could use the quadratic formula:
$r
=\dfrac{a\pm \sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}
$.

Comment: Please show the simplest form you found.  It will save others from reproducing your work.  It seems clear to multiply by $3$ to clear that denominator.  If you then multiply by $x+y$ you have a cubic, not a quadratic.  With one equation in two unknowns, you don't expect a unique solution unless there is an accident like $x^2+y^2=0$

Comment: @RossMillikan I tried taking a = xy and b = x+y

Comment: This reduces to your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168613/solving-cubic-diophantine-equation) as Inzit has shown.  If you are solving over the integers as in that one, *please* say so.  Then you are done.  Without solving over the integers, you **can't** use the quadratic formula.  You have a nice cubic curve because you have one equation in two unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

This can be help

$3xy(x+y) = (x+y)^3 - 35 \Leftrightarrow$

$3x^2y + 3xy^2 = x^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + y^3 - 35 \Leftrightarrow$

$x^3 + y^3 = 35$

Comment: I had that before, I'm trying to solve backwards. I want to use the quadratic formula to solve my equation. How can I do that?

Comment: @rachel:  this is a cubic, not a quadratic.  The quadratic formula will not help.  In addition, you have one equation in two unknowns.  In normal cases (like this one unless you are solving over the integers) you expect a one dimensional continuum of solutions.  Inspection gives $2,3$ as a solution.

Comment: But, the solution of $x^3 + y^3 = 35$ is a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$, now if you search integers solutions you can use
$(x+y)(x^2 - xy + y^2) = 35$ and separate in case

Comment: How do I do it?

Comment: @RossMillikan Look at what I have added.

Comment: @rachel:  If you are looking for integer solutions, the factorization says that $x+y$ and $x^2-xy+y^2$ are both factors of $35$.  There aren't many to try.  Now you have two equations in two unknowns (once for each way to factor $35$).  You should have said if you were only interested in integer solutions.

Comment: @RossMillikan I already know the solution, i want to know how to solve it using the quadratic equation, and yes I do mean quadratic. How can I use a substitution to create a quadratic equation.

Comment: Rachel, what is the quadratic equation used for?

Comment: @rachel: you can't magically turn a cubic into a quadratic.  Factoring it will get you a quadratic if you are only interested in integers.  What you can do in the integers is say $x+y=1,5,7,35, x^2-xy+y^2=35,7,5,1$ and solve the simultaneous equations four times.  Each one will give a quadratic, which you can use your formula on.  Most will not give integer solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I was typing the same as Inzit did, so I shall not repeat.

After simplification, you end with something very simple which is $x^3+y^3=35$ and the solutions, at leat in the real domain, are just $y=\sqrt[3]{35-x^3}$ or $x=\sqrt[3]{35-y^3}$.

I do not think that you could get anything else and in any manner, this is not relevant from quadratic equation except if you define $Y=\pm y^{3/2}$ or $X=\pm x^{3/2}$. In such a case, the equation transforms to $X^2+Y^2=35$.

Comment: Can you look at my question again. I added some stuff. Can you see if that approach is correct?

Comment: I loked at but : what is $r$ ? How do you now go from $r$ to $x$ and $y$ ? How can you say that $a$ and $b$ are known since these are the unknwons you look for ? I probably misunderstand something.